# Регулярное выражение в JS, которое позволяет только буквы и цифры

Tags: javascript

Хочу убрать из принимаемой строки все лишние символы, оставить только кириллицу/латиницу и цифры.

Пользуюсь методом replace, поэтому решения в других топиках не подходят.

Comment: Предоставьте пример в виде кода.

Comment: почему не подходят? вполне подходят

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const s = 'abcэюя123!@#'
const p = /[^a-zа-я0-9]+/g

alert (s.replace (p, ''))
```

Comment: ничего не забыли? Тогда попробуйте: `const s = 'Новогодняя ёлка from China';`

Comment: Неа, пусть хоть немного подумает.

Comment: Вы про заглавные и пробелы?)